# Action class in C++? (equivalent to C#)

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, lambda, action

In my C# game engine, I used to handle ordered drawing by adding/removing action to a manager object, which sorted the actions by priority, then executed them.

Here is a very simplified example:

```
class DrawManager
{
    public List<Tuple<Action, int>> DrawActions = new List<Tuple<Action, int>>();
    void Draw() { foreach (var tuple in DrawActions) tuple.Item1(); }
}

class Example
{
    DrawManager manager;

    Example()
    {
        manager.DrawActions.Add(new Tuple<Action, int>(DrawBackground, 0));
        manager.DrawActions.Add(new Tuple<Action, int>(DrawForeground, 100));
    }
    ~Example()
    {
        manager.DrawActions.Remove(manager.DrawActions.Find(x => x.Item1 == DrawBackground));
        manager.DrawActions.Remove(manager.DrawActions.Find(x => x.Item1 == DrawForeground));
    }

    void DrawBackground() { /* draw something */ }
    void DrawForeground() { /* draw something */ }
}
```

By adding some helper methods, the code becomes very elegant and easy to use in my engine.

I've moved to C++ recently, and I can't find any easy way to achieve the same result.

I tried using std::function, but in order to remove the method on object destruction, I had to store the draw method in a pointer owned by the caller, then wrap it into a lambda and pass it in. Very inelegant and time consuming.

Is there any way to get code similar to the one shown in the C# example?

Comment: Something similar here if this helps? http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?489732.html

Comment: Is the DrawManager object in the Example class shared by other objects?

Comment: Could you show an example of what you did with `std::function`? Because I can't decipher your description. :)

Comment: I think I understand your problem, you're trying to figure out how to do this: `Find(x => x.Item1 == DrawBackground));` -- but you can't, because `std::function` is not comparable.  Is that correct?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes it is shared. Also, my problem is that I can't set a std::function object to a non-lambda method. Example: void draw() { } ... std::function<void()> func = draw; - does not compile

Comment: Error for the above example is "conversion from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void()>' requested"

Comment: @Vee: Can we see your code?  Because you can set an `std::function` to a non-lambda object: http://liveworkspace.org/code/d59588c8ef4e5816099f9ba4eb3f8285

Comment: @BenjaminLindley here: http://pastie.org/5127969 - line 19 in CWall.cpp gives that error

Comment: Your function has the wrong signature.  It's a member function, so it has an implicit argument (this).  Try this: `std::function<void(CWall)> func = draw;` and you will see that it compiles.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley it still gives me the same error. I also tried void(CWall*), but with no success. It says "unresolved overloaded function type" - what does it mean?

Comment: Okay, I didn't notice that it was inheriting from another class.  So you'll need to disambiguate it from the parent class' draw function: `std::function<void(CWall&)> func = &CWall::draw;`

Comment: Great, it seems to compile now:) mind posting this as an answer, so that I can set it as accepted?

Comment: Look at this implementation of C# actions in C++:
[C# actions in C++11][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915573/c-sharp-actions-in-c11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::function` in place of `Action`:

```
typedef std::function<void()> Action;
std::vector<std::pair<Action, int> > DrawActions;
void Draw() {
    for_each(DrawActions.begin(), DrawActions.end(), [](std::pair<Action, int>& a) {
       a.first(); 
    });
}
```

Comment: He's doing that.  I think his problem is that he doesn't know how to remove the functions from the vector, because he can't find them, because `std::function`s are not comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Some other idea not using std::function, it uses std::set and you create a class for each action you want to execute. The idea would be that the action classes are defined in the cpp file (not in header files, unless they are shared) of the class that uses them, they are completely hidden.

First define the *Action* class, it has a pure virtual *execute*, a priority level and a pointer to some owner. The idea is to not create other classes, tuples, but use the *Action* class to store these values:

```
class Action
{
public:
    Action(const int priority, void * owner) : priority(priority), owner(owner) {}
    virtual ~Action() {}

    virtual void execute() = 0;

    struct PrioritySorter
    {
        bool operator()(Action* a, Action* b)
        {
            return a->priority < b->priority;
        }
    };

    bool ownerIs(void * owner) const { return this->owner == owner; }

private:
    const int priority;
    void * owner;
};
```

Then create some actions:

```
class DrawBackgroundAction : public Action
{
public:
    DrawBackgroundAction(const int priority, void * owner) : Action(priority, owner) {}

    void execute()
    {
        cout << "drawing background" << endl;
    }
};

class DrawForegroundAction : public Action
{
public:
    DrawForegroundAction(const int priority, void * owner) : Action(priority, owner) {}

    void execute()
    {
        cout << "drawing foreground!!!" << endl;
    }
};

class DrawSomethingElseAction : public Action
{
public:
    DrawSomethingElseAction(const int priority, void * owner) : Action(priority, owner) {}

    void execute()
    {
        cout << "drawing something else" << endl;
    }
};
```

The *DrawManager* takes care of storing the actions in a sorted set by priority, and if want to delete the "owned" actions (some other class) you can do it.

```
class DrawManager
{
public:
    DrawManager() {}
    ~DrawManager()
    {
        for ( ActionList::iterator i = actions.begin(), e = actions.end(); i != e; i++ )
        {
            delete *i;
        }
        actions.clear();
    }

    void draw()
    {
        for ( ActionList::iterator i = actions.begin(), e = actions.end(); i != e; i++ )
        {
            (*i)->execute();
        }
    }

    void addAction(Action* action)
    {
        actions.insert(action);
    }

    void removeOwnedActions(void * owner)
    {
        for ( ActionList::iterator i = actions.begin(), e = actions.end(); i != e; i++)
        {
            if ( (*i)->ownerIs(owner) )
            {
                delete *i;
                actions.erase(i);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    typedef std::set<Action*,Action::PrioritySorter> ActionList;
    ActionList actions;
};
```

Now the example class:

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example()
    {
        manager.addAction(new DrawForegroundAction(100,this));
        manager.addAction(new DrawBackgroundAction(0,this));
        manager.addAction(new DrawSomethingElseAction(50,this));
    }

    void drawAll()
    {
        manager.draw();
    }

    void removeTheActionsIfYouWant()
    {
        manager.removeOwnedActions(this);
    }

private:
    DrawManager manager;
};
```

And the test:

```
int main()
{
    Example ex;

    cout << "Drawing all" << endl;

    ex.drawAll();

    ex.removeTheActionsIfYouWant();

    cout << "Drawing again" << endl;

    ex.drawAll();

    return 0;
}
```